# I get "Invalid" for @angular/common@9.1.0-next.4 while running "npm ls rxjs". How can I fix this?

Tags: angular, npm

When I run "npm ls rxjs" I get this:

```
+-- @angular-devkit/core@9.1.0-next.3
| `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
+-- @angular/cli@9.1.13
| +-- @angular-devkit/core@9.1.13
| | `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| +-- @angular-devkit/schematics@9.1.13
| | +-- @angular-devkit/core@9.1.13
| | | `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| | `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| +-- @schematics/angular@9.1.13
| | `-- @angular-devkit/core@9.1.13
| |   `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| +-- @schematics/update@0.901.13
| | +-- @angular-devkit/core@9.1.13
| | | `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| | `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
| `-- inquirer@7.1.0
|   `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
+-- @angular/common@9.1.0-next.4 invalid
| `-- rxjs@6.5.4 deduped
...
```

What does invalid means and how can I fix invalid packages?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `package-lock.json` file (if it exists in your root folder) and delete the entire `node_modules` folder. Then try to run `npm install` again. Now see that whether it resolves your issue.

Comment: I tried this now npm install gives me an error. I will investigate. I think one of my colleagues in the project used npm install --force